# set image quality in Imagemagick

Tags: php, image, imagemagick

I to set the quality of the img but it dosent work.

```
  $image = 'the path to the img';
 /*** a new imagick object ***/
        $im = new Imagick();

        /*** ping the image ***/
        $im->pingImage($image);

        /*** read the image into the object ***/
        $im->readImage( $image );

        $im->setImageFormat( "png" );

        $im->setImageCompression(imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
        $im->setImageCompressionQuality(1);
        $im->stripImage();

        $im->cropThumbnailImage(90,90);

        /*** write image to disk ***/
        $im->writeImage( "tmp/spork1.png" );

        $im->destroy();
```

I try with  `$im->setCompressionQuality(1);` but dosent work then i google it and some people suggest to use `$im->setImageCompressionQuality(1);` but no effect what so ever

Comment: What do you mean by "it dosent work."

Comment: The file size is not changing. I upload one img and i converted with GD with 90 Quality = 1,5 kb and for Imagemagick when Quality is set to 1 the img size is 47 kb if is set to 100 again 47 kb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if you can adjust compression on a lossless format like a PNG I believe this is for JPEGS.

In your code you are setting the image type to png and the compression type to jpeg I am pretty sure this won't work.

Perhaps Try:

```
$im->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_LZW);

$im->setImageCompressionQuality(3);
```

You might want to look to optipng or pngcrush to get your file size down...

Comment: I just change the img format to jpg to able to use imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG